# how does mongodb do a 42T drive per node

Tags: mongodb

We had heard mongodb had one client with 42T per node and I am wondering more about this.  I know cassandra has Bloomfilters that skipp hitting disk to find out which file a row might be in.

1. Does mongodb have something similar to bloomfilters?
2. IS mongodb using something similar to SSTables?
3. I did read mongodb does compaction just like cassandra, I would think this would be an awfully long process with a 42T node????

I guess I don't know what terms to search for as I research mongodb here(in cassandra they are called SSTables).

thanks,
Dean

Comment: document is not going to be read from disk into RAM unless it's accessed.  Indexes are used to know which documents need to be accessed.  Good index strategy will mean only full indexes, and some small subset of documents (that are being accessed) need to be in RAM aka need to be read from disk.

Comment: so can mongodb support billions of rows per node.  I can't find anything on it's compaction algorithms like size tiered vs. leveled compaction whcih are are well documented google methods for compacting as your data set size grows.  Implementing one of these is typically critical for finding information fast.  With huge amounts of info, there needs to be indexes into where the rowkey(and it's row exist).  How does it all work?

Comment: it works by using indexes which give you direct pointer to the record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB does not support online compaction. In fact, data fragmentation is a current problem in systems with many doc updates. To prevent data fragmentation MongoDB tries to calculate an automated padding factor, minimizing the number of data moves.

The compact command blocks the entire database until it finished. Besides, MongoDB does not support dictionary compression, so field names takes space on every object stored. I guess the layout used by MongoDB is not any fancy data structure. It's simply composed of header (offset, length...), bson data and padding factor.

Since MongoDB is not a key/value or columnar database it doesn't use SSTables (efficient data structure for columnar layout). Every file created for the database is named "extent".

AFAIK, MongoDB doesn't use bloom filters.

Comment: I did read some stuff on the compact command...sweet...this seems to be aligning with what I am finding so 42T seems to be really hard to do then with our model I think.